# How to access navigation title from embedded container

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I have a view controller (Left on attached screen) embedded in a navigation container.
I want the container view controller (Top right on attached screen) to change the navigation title of the parent view controller.

I have tried the following script from my container vier controller, but it does not work.

```
    self.parentViewController?.title = {Value}
    self.presentingViewController?.title = {Value}
```

Please let me know what should have been the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the navbar's title you need to access it through the `navigationItem` property like so:

```
parentViewController?.navigationItem.title = "Value"
```

Also, ensure that your container views are connected properly in Interface Builder.

[image]

See how under "Presenting Segues" and "Embed" the View Controller for the `ContainerView` is hooked up for `viewDidLoad`. If this is set up incorrectly it may explain why your `parentViewController` returned `nil`.

Comment: The problem is that the parentViewController is nil. Normally setting a title to the viewController will cascade the title to the navigationController.

Comment: Normally, `parentViewController` would not return nil see my edits. @HamDongKyun

Comment: Funny thing is that, it is set as your sample above, but it still not showing as it should.

Comment: Hmmm. @HamDongKyun , are you getting any error messages or anything odd logged to the console? Also, check that there isn't any unknown connections in the connections inspector (for any category), as these can cause strange errors.

Comment: Zip.. on the console and no other peculiar connections.

Comment: Resolved it by using parent?.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title